# Reseed table with key already used as foreign key

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, relational-database, identity

Is it possible to Reseed the key (IDENTITY) of a table already used as foreign key on other tables?
Is there a safe way to "propagate" the new serials on the other tables?
Should I create a new column with a new clean Identity key, and then update the records on the other tables according to the new  serial?
I'm working with SQLSERVER 2012

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can define foreign keys to propagate new values when the foreign key value changes.

These are called cascading constraints, and the syntax is:

```
alter table add constraint fk_table1_table2_id
    foreign key table2(t1_id) references table1(t1_id)
         on update cascade;
```

Generally, there is also `on delete`.  You can refer to the documentation for your database to learn about them.

Then, you can "turn off" the automatic generation of the identity column and update the values for the keys in `table1`.  These are then propagated to all tables where the foreign keys are cascading update foreign keys.

Note:  You have to do this for ALL foreign keys, if that is your intention.

In general, this approach is NOT recommended, because it can result is a lot of changes to the database.  However, if you need to accomplish this for some reason, then you can.

Note:  If you are doing this to remove gaps, then don't bother.  Gaps pose no issue in primary keys.

Comment: I knew about the UPDATE CASCADE, but I was worried about the consistency of the result during a RESEED

Comment: @Frikazoid . . . `reseed` has nothing to do with it.  The `update` is what gets cascaded.